# want to check if a table exists before making transaction

Tags: java, sqlite, jdbc

I am writing an application using java and sqlite database. I am making many inserts into a database. Each time before inserting I have used the following sql statement and executed it using java

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS TABLE_NAME "
        + " (ID INT NOT NULL, "
        + " PERCENT INT NOT NULL, "
        + " TASK_DATA VARCHAR(1000) ,"
        + " CONSTRAINT pk_progressID PRIMARY KEY (ID))
```

However this is not a good practice to execute this statement each time. What is the alternative such that it also checks that the table exists or not and creates it also if it doesn't?

Comment: Why do you think that this is not good practice?

Comment: I suggest you look at tools that check and if necessary upgrade your database schema at start if necessary (eg Liquibase, flyway) instead of just checking randomly just before use.

Answer (score 2):

## Database Migration

This problem is called “database migration”. On every database connection made by your app, you need to know the database structure and data is in a known expected condition and configuration.

One solution is to internally label the current state of your database, a sort of version number. Of course a database table might be the perfect place to store this versioning info.

I could go on and guide you through the kinds of versioning you could do, how to have your app run SQL scripts and Java code needed to bring any instance of your database up-to-date with your current latest expectations. But no need for me to do that explanation.

Two very good projects have already been built to do these chores of database migration. No code for you to write! Either of these projects can be plugged into your app.

- [Flyway](https://flywaydb.org/)
- [Liquibase](http://www.liquibase.org/)

Every time your app connects to the database it checks the latest known versioning info stored in an extra table. If the DB instance is out-of-date, these tools run the SQL scripts and/or Java code needed to create/modify table definitions, insert/modify/delete rows, and so on.

Of course you must carefully write, test, and archive those SQL scripts and updating Java code as you develop your project.

Answer (score 1):

This is a common problem of software version updates & old database data.

Best have a database entry with your own version number.

Then at program start you can check and update accordingly, even across several versions, in a defined manner.

```
while (database.version() < software.version) {
    software.updateToNextFrom(database.version());
}
```